# Advice for batch processing with calls to distributed systems in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, batch-processing, distributed-computing

I was hoping to get some tips on issues that seem to reoccur on almost every project at our team.

In those projects, the main goal usually is to perform some kind of processing on a large number of 'items'.
The 'processing' is basically a sequence of actions, each of which can fail for various reasons.

Maybe I can explain it best, by describing an example application.

Imagine the following as the simplified version of one of our applications: (which is probably some 1000 LoC in reality)

```
foreach (var pdfFile in unprocessedPdfFiles)
{
    var mailWasSent = SendMail(pdfFile);

    if(!mailWasSent)
    {
        PrintFile(pdfFile);
    }

    MarkAsProcessed(pdfFile);
}
```

While these are the problematic requirements:

- Each day there are some thousands of files to be processed
- To process a file, we need to perform a mix of database operations and calls to external systems (no transaction possible)
- SendMail() may fail for various reasons, i.e.

  - Connection to mail server fails (the attempt should be automatically retried later, without blocking the processing of other files)
  - Address misspelled (may have to be corrected manually and retried after that)
  - Other unexpected reasons, which nobody would have expected and may only become clear after the application is running productive
- A correctly sent mail could 'bounce' back - maybe days after it was sent. It is desired to print out the file after we are notified about the bounce.
- The actual printing of files may fail without a possibility for the application to notice. (i.e. printer malfunction)
- Our boss may ask the following questions:

  - What files have been sent or printed out during the last week?
  - File ABC was expected to get printed out, but it's missing. Did the application try to print it? If yes, when?
  - What happened to file XYZ, how often and when did we try to send and print it?

And here is what in my opinion are our biggest difficulties:

1. To keep record of what the application 'does', we need to have a searchable history of:

   - which items were processed correctly
   - what errors happend while processing items
2. We to find out how to 'fix' the failed items efficiently and without side effects.

   - in some cases, it's feasible to mark a failed item as 'unprocessed' again, so it simply gets processed again
   - but in other cases, we can't just reprocess the item from start because a previously failed attempt may already have caused side effects which could not be rolled back. (A way to resume the processing at the previously failing step may be good)
3. Often, it only makes sense to repeat a processing step after 'something' else has happend           (Maybe we need to fix a bug, or an external web service needs to become available again.) That means we can't just use retry-loop's everywhere, but need to remember the error in a way to be able to inspect and retry it later.

   - We would like to keep track of 'fixing attempts' and what happened afer somebody tried to fix an item
4. The code gets cluttered up with lots of non-business logic, mainly because of the other issues. (Exception handling, Control logic, etc.)

(Note: Processing perfomance is usually no issue.)

Here is how we tried to solve these problems in the past:

- All processing is done inside a C# loop in a windows service
- Items to process are represented by rows in a database table (called "Trigger"-rows)
- After processing, trigger rows are marked with a status flag with one of these meanings: "done", "error while printing", "unknown error", etc.
- Some flat file logging for last resort troubleshooting (NLog)
- Use SQL on trigger table to get information about processed items
- set trigger status to "unprocessed" to repeat item with error

I am sure that out there are a lot of experts with plenty of long-term experiences in this area. (whatever it is called)
But I couldn't find much practical advice by searching the web, so I was hoping that here at stackoverflow I could get some advice.

Interesting frameworks I found online, but have hesitated to use so far:

- The 'BatchFlow' Framework (also on NuGet)

  - I guess it could help to keep our code cleaner, but would leave us with all the other problems, like logging and asynchronous error recovering.
- Messaging Frameworks, like MassTransit or EasyNetQ. 
  I can see how messaging could help to solve some of our problems, like being able to retry single steps of a workflow later, but:

  - No matter what framework, there never seems to be an easy way to inspect and retry error messages.
    It looks like every messaging framework basically just throws error messages to an error queue and thats it.
    But in order to inspect and retry these errors it seems that you always have to implement quite a bit of additional logic.
    One idea would be to consume all error messages and put them to a database for that purpose, but then I think
    why isn't something like that already part of the framework? ... and how on earth are other people handling their errors?
  - I would expect that, with messaging, it should be easy to save a history log on what messages were processed in relation to 
    a business transaction, but that also seems to be something you would have to implement completely on top of a messaging 
    framework. (or maybe I'm trying to solve a problem with the wrong method here.)

Hope the post was not too confusing, but I will gladly elaborate where needed.

Comment: Just read an article about "Process Integration" and the "Process Manager" pattern. I think that's exactly what I was looking for!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647433.aspx

Comment: Btw I still did not find a (single) answer to my question, but it turns out there are other people thinking about the same stuff. I just found this blog post: https://jimmybogard.com/refactoring-towards-resilience-a-primer/

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a big problem to be solved all at once.

This is an enterprise level problem, and best to be solved on a higher level of abstraction. In SOA term, you have to break down the system to smaller applications that do only what it needs to do. Think SOLID[1]. Think Single Responsibility.

After breaking down the application into smaller applications, you can use an Integration hub like Mule[2] or Apache Camel[3] to integrate the exchange of messages.

Microservice architecture [4] fits the problem nicely by creating boundaries isolating services with one another. Group services by their business domain or functions.

Here is a few tip that will make your life easier:

1. Use managed cloud services like AWS to reduce the application's responsibility. For example, for file management, use AWS S3 [5]. To send an email, use AWS SNS Topic [6], which allows you to send email reliably. Alternatively, use AWS SES which is a managed SMTP server. The advantage of using managed service is that you will not need to handle the low-level work like logging or managing failures. Let PAAS handle that for you.
2. Message queue's responsibility is to provide a durable, reliable channel for sharing information. It is used to reliably receive and send messages to multiple consumer and producer, in a loosely coupled way. It will not also responsible for helping you write to a database.
3. If you want to write also to a database while processing it, consider writing your data to a stream like Apache Kafka [7] or AWS Kinesis Stream [8]. You can create multiple recipients to listen to the stream, and act on the data. For example, one client can process the data and save the outcome to a database. Another client listener can be responsible for logging the data.
4. Use a retry policy for all the API calls. Transient faults like delays and timeout are very common in a distributed processing. They can go away the after a while, and can be handled using retries. There is a nice retry policy framework written in C# known as Polly [9].
5. Should there be a failure that cannot be resolved after maximum retry limit, send a message to a Dead Letter Queue [10]. AWS Lamdba support execution of code that sends a failed execution as a message to a dead letter queue. AWS Lambda will retry automatically, so you can focus on writing the code to do what it needs to. Any failed execution would go to the DLQ. Another Lambda function can be used to process the message in the DLQ.

I hope you start to see how the problem can be broken down, and using some good principles, you will be able to build a far more robust, scalable and resilient system.

[1] https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp

[2] https://developer.mulesoft.com/

[3] http://camel.apache.org/

[4] http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html

[5] https://aws.amazon.com/s3/

[6] https://aws.amazon.com/sns/

[7] https://kafka.apache.org

[8] https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/

[9] https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

[10] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dlq.html